# Active drop down links

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm trying to create a tabbed accordion style drop down. I've been playing around with the jQuery for a while but can't get the active state working at 100%.

I'm pretty sure it's the JS I'm messing up on.

```
$('.service-button').click(function () {
    var itemid = '#div' + $(this).attr('target'); //id of the element to show/hide.

    if ($('.active').length === 0) {
        $(itemid).slideDown();
        $(itemid).addClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('new');

    } else if (itemid == "#" + $('.active').attr('id')) {
        $('.active').slideUp();
        $(itemid).removeClass('active');
        $(this).removeClass('new');

    } else {
        $('.active').slideUp(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $('.service-button').removeClass('new');
            if ($(".targetDiv:animated").length === 0) {
                $(itemid).slideDown();
                $(itemid).addClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('new');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I've created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/NWxLe/

The drop down is working correctly and the active state is applied to the first tab. However the problem occurs when I try to open another tab. The active state is removed from the previous one but not added to the new one. I hope this makes sense.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain 1) What you mean by "tabbed accordion style dropdown" 2) What is happening 3) What you want to happen. Saying you messed up on the JS is not enough for us to know what went wrong, since we don't know which part of what we're looking at is what you wanted to happen.

Comment: I'm seeing your `active` class being added to the `tab-content` just like it says in the code. Was this not what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that in a bit of a rush. Basically what is happening is the drop down is working correctly, however when you go to open another tab the active class does not get added to it. It is removed from the previously open one but not added to the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could be simplified a fair bit. You really only need one `if` and one `else`, because either the tab that you click is either active already or is it not

```
$('.service-button').click(function () {
    var itemid = '#div' + $(this).attr('target');
    var $activetab = $(this);

    // If the tab is not already active    
    if (!$activetab.hasClass('new')) {
        $('.new').removeClass('new');
        $('.active').slideUp();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');

        // Wait for the slideUp to complete (default slideUp time is 500ms)
        // This is to keep the same behavior as your linked demo
        setTimeout(function() { 
            $activetab.addClass('new');
            $(itemid).slideDown();
            $(itemid).addClass('active')
        }, 500);
    } else { // If the tab is active already
        $('.new').removeClass('new');
        $('.active').slideUp();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NWxLe/35/)

Comment: This is perfect Zach, thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Do you need collapsible accordion or tab ? if you want accordion here you go :

```
    <!--1st accordion -->
<div id = "accordion1" class = "E W accordion-item">
    <div class = "accordion-item-header clearfix">
        <div>
            <a data-accordion = "" href = "#accordion1"><i class = "accord-opener"></i><span>click Me</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "accordion-item-body ">
        <div class = "data-content">
            <h3>This is accordion content</h3>            
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
<!--end accordion -->
<!--2nd accordion -->
<div id = "accordion2" class = "E W accordion-item">
    <div class = "accordion-item-header clearfix">
        <div>
          <a data-accordion = "" href = "#accordion2"><i class = "accord-opener"></i><span>click Me</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "accordion-item-body ">
        <div class = "data-content">
            <h3>This is accordion content</h3>            
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
<!--end accordion -->
<!--3rd accordion -->
<div id = "accordion3" class = "E W accordion-item">
    <div class = "accordion-item-header clearfix">
        <div>
            <a data-accordion = "" href = "#accordion3"><i class = "accord-opener"></i><span>click Me</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "accordion-item-body ">
        <div class = "data-content">
            <h3>This is accordion content</h3>            
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
<!--end accordion -->
```

Sample CSS :

```
.accordion-item-header {
 display:block;
 width:340px;
 height:40px;
 background:#454545;
 border:1px solid yellow;   
 }
.accordion-item-header > div > a { 
 color:#f8f8f8;
 line-height:40px;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding-left:10px
 }
.accordion-item-body {
 width:338px;
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid black;
 display:none;
 }
```

And fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/NWxLe/33/

Comment: This does not attempt to solve the issue with the code